# How can I convert this function into Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, real-time

How can I convert this function into an `AngularJS` directive?
I want to make it validate user input in real time. But even when I'm trying to use it as regular function in controller I'm getting an error:

> "Error: pesel.substring is not a function"

```
function decode(pesel) 
{
    var year=parseInt(pesel.substring(0,2),10);
    var month = parseInt(pesel.substring(2,4),10)-1;
    var day = parseInt(pesel.substring(4,6),10);

    if(month>80) {
        year = year + 1800;
        month = month - 80;
    }
    else if(month > 60) {
        year = year + 2200;
        month = month - 60;
    }
    else if (month > 40) {
        year = year + 2100;
        month = month - 40;
    }
    else if (month > 20) {
        year = year + 2000;
        month = month - 20;
    }
    else {
        year += 1900;
    }

    var birthday=new Date();
    birthday.setFullYear(year, month, day);

    var weights = [9,7,3,1,9,7,3,1,9,7];
    var sum = 0

    for(var i=0;i<weights.length;i++) {
        sum+=(parseInt(pesel.substring(i,i+1),10) * weights[i]);
    }

    sum=sum % 10;
    var valid=(sum===parseInt(pesel.substring(10,11),10));

    //sex
    if(parseInt(pesel.substring(9,10),10) % 2 === 1) { 
        var sex='m';
    } else {
        var sex='f';
    }

    return {valid:valid,sex:sex,date:birthday};
}
```

Comment: most probably `pesel` variable is not a string, please log it's type in your console and share the result with us `console.log(typeof(pesel))`

Answer (score 0):

As [Abdo stated above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108544/how-can-i-convert-this-function-into-angular-directive#comment59859465_36108544) the value you are passing to your function, `pesel`, probably isn't a string.

The first line in your function should be:

```
pesel = (pesel || '').toString();
```

This line makes sure you don't stringify falsey variables and will make sure `pesel` is in fact a string.

Comment: Thank you, I checked it and it's string and it's working now. I don't know why it didn't before maybe I wrongly implemented it.

But still how can I make it into directive and validate input with it real time (when user is typing)?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to validate some input, consider as a better option to create a parser/formatter pair or a validator for that purpose.

Use formatter/parsers for retrieving birthday and sex values, and a validator to check the value.

Best